# Update huge row of model from Foreigner Table to Current Table in Django Rest

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 3 models and an abstract model in Django Model.

I want to add Field in ScentData and copy Domain from Subdomain to Scentdata.

```py
# Abstract Model
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='Create At',
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = NoDeleteManager()
    objects_with_deleted = models.Manager()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['created_at']
```

```py
class Domain(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=False,
        default=''
    )


class SubDomain(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=False,
        default=''
    )
    domain = models.ForeignKey(
        'Domain',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='subdomains'
    )


class ScentData(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=''
    )
    subdomain = models.ForeignKey(
        'SubDomain',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='scentdata_subdomain'
    )
```

But now I add one more `domain` field to **ScentData** Model.

```py
class ScentData(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=''
    )
    subdomain = models.ForeignKey(
        'SubDomain',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='scentdata_subdomain'
    )
    domain = models.ForeignKey(
        'Domain',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='scentdata_domain',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def set_domain(self):
        self.domain = self.subdomain.domain
        self.save()
        return self
```

I have written **ModelViewSet** to run function `set_domain` in **ScentData** but I have 200K of rows in Scentdata so my server can not handle that long time to change.
Here is my ViewSet below.

```py
class ScentDataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ScentData.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], url_path="reset_domain")
    def reset_domain(self, pk=None, **kwargs):
        scent_data = ScentData.objects.all()
        for scent_data_obj in scent_data:
            scent_data_obj.set_domain()
        return Response({"detail": "success"})
```

Is there any technique to move **Domain** to **ScentData** Faster?

Comment: Have a look at [bulk update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

Answer (score 1):

You can improve this process with [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`bulk_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update):

```
updated_scent_data = []

scent_data = ScentData.objects.select_related('subdomain__domain').all()

for scent_data_obj in scent_data:
    scent_data_obj.domain = scent_data_obj.subdomain.domain
    updated_scent_data.append(scent_data_obj)

ScentData.objects.bulk_update(updated_scent_data, ['domain'])
```

`select_related` so each iteration of `scent_data` will not have to hit the DB per `scent_data_obj` just to get `subdomain.domain`.

`bulk_update` to update all `ScentData` objects in one DB hit.